# Unable to load model from tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load a model from tensor flow but its not working.

here is the code::

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub


print('before')
embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")
print('after')

embeddings = embed([
    "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
    "I am a sentence for which I would like to get its embedding"])

print(embeddings)
```

I dont get an error, the code just gets stuck and does not run.
any help

Comment: It looks like you just need to wait for the model to load. It worked for me. If you want to save it after its loaded, consider saving `embed` into a `.pkl` file using python's `pickle` module.

Comment: How long did you have to wait for it to load? @vs07

Comment: A couple minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no problem** in your code.
It work fine on my system.

The size of the model is about **1GB**, so it will take some time to load it (for me it takes 20-30 sec). Check your **internet connectivity** or you can try to run the code on other system like **Google colab**.